# \excludecomment and \newcommand using it

Tags: macros, comments

I have a problem with `\excludecomment` from comment package and a `\newcommand`.

The following codes work good, which means, it can generate the desired pdf output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{dontshow}

\begin{document}
This is a test.

\begin{dontshow}
test test test
\end{dontshow}

\end{document}
```

However, if I add the following:

```
\newcommand{\noshow}[2]{#1=#2 \begin{dontshow}#2=#1\end{dontshow} #1=#2}
\noshow{abc}{def}
```

It generates an error:

```
(c:/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty
Excluding comment 'comment') Excluding comment 'dontshow' (./test.aux))
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test.tex

?
```

How can I use 'comment' in a `\newcommand`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The environments of the `comment` package need to be on their own:

> The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No
>   starting spaces, nothing after it.

AFAIK they don't work in macros like yours because they skip everything verbatim.
There you could use if-switches for most content (except for unbalanced if-switches).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifshow
%\showtrue
\showfalse

\usepackage{comment}
\ifshow
\includecomment{dontshow}
\else
\excludecomment{dontshow}
\fi

\newcommand{\noshow}[2]{#1=#2 \ifshow #2=#1 \fi #1=#2}

\begin{document}
This is a test.

\begin{dontshow}
test test test
\end{dontshow}

\noshow{abc}{def}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. From your codes, if I input `\noshow{abc}{def}`, that is same as: `abc=def \begin{dontshow} def=abc\end{dontshow} abc=def` ? I don't quite understand how `\ifshow' connects to `dontshow' _environment_.

Comment: The if-switches are not directly connected to the environments. The `show` name can be changed to a different name if you want. Both are getting coupled just after loading the package when the if-switch in- or excludes the `dontshow` environment.

Comment: Thanks the hint about spaces and stuff after the begin/end command helped me fixiing my problem with the comment package