# comment package - \excludecomment{} gives error

Tags: floats, comments, draft

I'm trying to generate a pdf file without the pictures for draft revision, and as seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50904/how-can-i-remove-the-figures-from-a-draft-of-my-document) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12232/excludecomment-and-newcommand-using-it) the `\excludecomment{}` is not working for me.

Here is my error:

```
line 31: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup \end{wrapfigure}
line 31: Undefined control sequence \end{wrapfigure}
line 31: Missing number, treated as zero \end{wrapfigure}
line 31: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \end{wrapfigure}
```

given by my test code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3}    % use 1.5 line spacing
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}    % puts the figure wrapped

\newif\ifshow
%\showtrue
\showfalse


\usepackage{comment}
%\excludecomment{itemize}
\ifshow
\includecomment{wrapfigure}
\else
\excludecomment{wrapfigure}
\fi
\excludecomment{wrapfigure}


\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tempus convallis euismod. Vestibulum aliquet lacus at diam laoreet a scelerisque purus posuere.   

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{latex.png}
            \end{center}
            \caption{Caption}
            \label{fig:00}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

Neither using the `\removecomment{}` or the `if` sentence works.

Comment: What about the `[draft]` option for the `graphicx` package?

Comment: ..and [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks man! I've used your approach as is really easy to remove the pictures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Package `version`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3}    % use 1.5 line spacing
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}    % puts the figure wrapped

\newif\ifshow
%\showtrue
\showfalse

\usepackage{version}
\ifshow
  \includeversion{wrapfigure}
\else
  \excludeversion{wrapfigure}
\fi

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{latex.png}
            \end{center}
            \caption{Caption}
            \label{fig:00}
        \end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

### Package `comment`

The environment is an outer shell with its contents is set or is not depending on
`\excludeversion` or `\includeversion`. Also the environment markers have to be on a line
of their own. `\excludeversion` and `\includeversion` do not work well with existing environments. `\endwrapfigure` causes the error messages. Thus an additional wrapper environment is needed:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3}    % use 1.5 line spacing
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}    % puts the figure wrapped

\newif\ifshow
\showtrue
%\showfalse

\usepackage{comment}
\ifshow
  \includecomment{wrap}
\else
  \excludecomment{wrap}
\fi

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrap}
        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{latex.png}
            \end{center}
            \caption{Caption}
            \label{fig:00}   
        \end{wrapfigure}  
\end{wrap}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The both method worked perfectly!

I will mark as solved, however I will follow the comment from @Coretin and use the `[draft]` (or `[demo]`) option from `grapicx` because is simpler, does the job of removing the picture (or the big size of the PDF) and I do not need to edit the code (at least for the comment package).
(I should had searched with other terms on Google before getting lost on comment pkg. :D)