Why can't I exclude my answer environment?
Why can't I exclude my answer environment?
Edit 2: Actual code but the problem still exists.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\includecomment{answer} 
\renewenvironment{answer}{\par\color{red}}{}

\excludecomment{answer}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
%
\item Question 1
\begin{answer}
    Answwer 1
\end{answer}
%
\item Question 2
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Statement 1
    \begin{answer}
        Correct!
    \end{answer}
    \item Statement 2
    \begin{answer}
        Wrong!
    \end{answer}    
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}



What you put in edit of your question would be better to publish as an answer.

@D G, than please provide more realistic example which show your problem. I guess, that in real project you use packages or definitions, which some haw overwrite your solution. Since your project is unknown to us, we cant help you.

It seems that your question is duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12232/excludecomment-and-newcommand-using-it. Se if answer on it can help you.

As the answer Zarko linked explains, you must have only \begin{answer} and only \end{answer} on a line. Spaces are not allowed.
So, the following works for me:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\includecomment{answer}
\renewenvironment{answer}{\par\color{red}}{}

\excludecomment{answer}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  %
  \item Question 1
\begin{answer}
    Answwer 1
\end{answer}
  %
  \item Question 2
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Statement 1
\begin{answer}
        Correct!
\end{answer}
    \item Statement 2
\begin{answer}
        Wrong!
\end{answer}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


An alternative without using the comment package that may fit, using the new enumext package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumext}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumext}[save-ans=test]
  \item Question 1
    \anskey{Answer 1}
  \item Question 2
    \begin{enumext}
      \item Statement 1
      \anskey{Correct!}
      \item Statement 2
      \anskey{Wrong!}
    \end{enumext}
\end{enumext}

\printkeyans[columns=1]{test}
\end{document}

The show-ans key controls the visibility of answers.


Very interesting package. I will read the doc soon. :-)

It was created (as was scontents) for tasks like this :D
